# How to show save notification popup to user on breadcrumb click in angular 6

Tags: angular, popup, breadcrumbs

Ex : Home/Page1/Page2/Page3.
I have unsaved data in Page3. User click on Page2. I want to stay back in Page3 and notify the user . Using pop up saying "You have unsaved data and do you want to save?"

Comment: Are both in the same component?

Comment: No. Different component

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

A pseudo solution would be to use `CanDeactivate` route guard where you can have a reference to the form component.

Check whether the form is valid to return true to redirect otherwise alert a notification and return false

Sample code for

```
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router'
import { ContactComponent } from './contact.component'

export class CanDeactivateContact implements CanDeactivate<ContactComponent> {
  canDeactivate(component: ContactComponent): boolean {
    if(component.contactForm.dirty) {
      return confirm('are you sure you want to leave this page');
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

A sample stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-candeactivate-route-guard

Comment: I tried with DeactivateRouteGuard. it trigger only during page load. when i click on Breadcrumb Page2. it doesn't trigger DeactivateRouteGuard

Comment: @Shetty I have included a sample stackblitz which you can refer to